# Featch Installed SQL instance names on multiple servers

Tags: powershell

I writing this to get the list of installed instance on a remote sql server but it was failing  with below error I am going achieve this as follows

1. Read the list of servers names from my central db server
2. create a function that takes servers from step1 retrieved.

## Code

```
# -- Get the patch servers from central server  function
get-patchservers {
    # -- Where is your central patching database located?
    $sql_inst   = Read-Host "SQL instance hosting Patching DB; default: Severname\SQL201201"
    # -- Default patching control server to "ServerName\SQL201201"
    if($sql_inst -eq "") {$sql_inst="Severname\SQL201201"}
    # -- What's the name of your central patching database?
    $sql_db     = Read-Host "Name of Patching DB; default:patchdb"
    # -- Default datatabase for patching db
    if($sql_db -eq "") {$sql_db="patchdb" }
    # -- T-SQL to feacth server name from cerntral db
    $Tsql = "SELECT svr_name  FROM server"
    $ServerList = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Tsql -ServerInstance $sql_inst -Database $sql_db    #return $ServerList   

    foreach($Server in $ServerList) {
        ECHO $Server
        $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $Server)
        $regKey= $reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\MicrosoftSQL Server\\Instance Names\\SQL" )
        $instances = $regkey.GetValueNames()
        $instances
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the error?

Comment: This function is  failing with      Exception calling "OpenRemoteBaseKey" with "2" argument(s): "The network path was not found.
"
At line:26 char:3
+   $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey( "Localmachine", $Serv ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IOException

Comment: But this working as expected when i pass the value for $serverlist array

Answer (score 0):

I found what is causing here.  It looks problem with header returned by invoke-sqlcmd command